# Add custom file extended properties

Tags: c#, .net, windows-api-code-pack, file-properties, propertyhandler

After adding metadata property handler for .svg extension with [this tool](https://github.com/Dijji/FileMeta), I am able to add keywords to .svg files via Windows Explorer.

[image: FileMeta Association Manager]

I am now searching a way to add keywords via a C# application. I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337683/how-to-set-extended-file-properties#answer-37987288) but `System.AccessViolationException` is thrown with the code:

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell;

var tags = new[] {"foo", "bar"};
var file = ShellFile.FromFilePath(path);
// following statement throws System.AccessViolationException
file.Properties.System.Keywords.Value = tags;
```

What can be the cause?

---

Edit:

This method works correctly but `COMException` is thrown if tag length is too high.

```
using DSOFile;

var file = new OleDocumentProperties();
file.Open(path);
file.SummaryProperties.Keywords = string.Join(";", tags);
file.Close(true);
```

Comment: Since there are several, which [`WindowsAPICodePack` nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=WindowsAPICodePack) did you install?  (See [Windows API Code Pack: Where is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24081665/150605))  Possibly related: [C# WindowsApiCodepack PropertySystem AccessViolationException](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28076941/150605)

Comment: I tried nuget packages [by Aybe](https://github.com/aybe/Windows-API-Code-Pack-1.1) and by [Microsoft](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack)

Comment: @alex  Did you find a solution?

Comment: @AnnL. No, I am sorry. I abandoned this feature.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell;

var shellFile = ShellFile.FromParsingName(filePath);
// This one throws an exception
// shellFile.Properties.System.Keywords.Value = new[] { "test1", "test2" }; 
var writer = shellFile.Properties.GetPropertyWriter();
// This works, pass keywords as single string
writer.WriteProperty(SystemProperties.System.Keywords, "test1;test2", true);
writer.Close();
```